# Max refresh rate for raspberry pi 4?

Tags: pi-4

I'm thinking of using a raspberry pi 4 as thin client for game streaming.

I want to know what is the maximum refresh rate that the pi can reach at 1080p. I have searched a lot, but can´t find an answer apart from two screens at 1080@60hz. I want only one screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to know the exact refresh rate of the monitor? Well, it depends on the monitor and your setup.

Comment: Searched a lot?! Have you looked at this page describing [video options in config.txt.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

Comment: Yes, i've looked that, but i tought there were something wrong because the max is 1080@120 for both pi 3 and pi 4. My monitor is 144hz